# UICollectionViewCell dynamic width and fixed height

Tags: ios, gridview, uicollectionview, ios11, xcode9

I need to make UICollectionView cells in oval shape where height is fixed but width is dynamic and it has a limit also, if text longer than that, then text should scroll. Any third party option available for this or need to create own using UICollectionView. Please guide.

[image]

Below is the image what i am trying to achieve. I want to know before starting should i look for third parties or use UICollectionView to make own. I have short time to complete that's why to avoid time on searching asking in starting itself which direction to follow.Please guide.

Comment: You can get the width of String and according that you can set the size of width so you have to use sizeforitem method and you have to include UIcollectionFlowlayoutdelegate

Comment: Have a look of this repo https://github.com/riteshhgupta/TagCellLayout

Comment: @BhupatBheda this seems useful, but i am working on swift 4, it may not have support for it as it has 1 year old commit.

Comment: You definitely don't need a third-party library for something so simple.

Comment: Okay then go with my first suggestion i hope it will work !@iphone 6 or may be you can look out this one also https://codentrick.com/create-a-tag-flow-layout-with-uicollectionview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, i found a library [TagListView](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView) that can be installed through cocoapods with lots of customisation and swift 4 support also.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and Auto Layout to achieve this.

1. Create a UICollectionViewCell with a container view.
2. Pin this container view the edges of the cell with auto layout
3. Add a UILabel to this container view and pin it to all edges of the container view (give it a background color to distinguish from the cell background)
4. In the UICollectionViewCell subclass you'll want to round the corners of the container view, e.g. `self.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = self.containerView.height / 2`
5. In the UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate method, estimatedSizeForItem return an approximate size for the cell (auto layout will calculate the actual size.)

The important thing to remember is your cell needs to have enough constraints so that the auto layout engine can calculate the actual height and width based on the content.

Edit: If you want a fixed height, ensure your label can only have a single line. Or add a height constraint.

Comment: actually op is asking for dynamic width not dynamic height!

Comment: And why wouldn't this solution work for dynamic width...? I've edited to be less ambiguous, but the solution is the same.

Comment: you had written that autolayout can calculate actual height! that's why I have pointed out! now your edited answer is fine!

Comment: I found a useful library for the same. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

```
  let nw = intersts[indexPath.row]

    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1500)

    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: nw).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)], context: nil)
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]

    let yourLabelSize: CGSize = nw.size(withAttributes:attributes )
    var width1 = yourLabelSize.width + 30
    if width1 < 30 {
        width1 = 30
    }

    return CGSize(width: estimatedFrame.width+20, height: estimatedFrame.height+20)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just extend or implement @Tim answer. So after you build the cell as described in his answer, then specify the cell width and height to be flexible using the sample code below i.e similar to what he described

```
    let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let itemWidth = Constants.myCollectionViewItemWidth
    let itemHeight = Constants.myCollectionViewItemHeight
    collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout
```